# Grid.MVC date filter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, grid.mvc

I have a model bound to grid.MVC, every other filter works fine apart from the date picker filter.

I have added the grid.mvc.datepicker.css to the bundle and I am getting the date picker.

[image]

There are no errors in any of the js and all the js files load properly

And this is how I initiate the column in the view

```
columns.Add(o => o.VoucherType.Expiry)
    .Titled("Expiry")
    .SetFilterWidgetType("")
    .Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
```

> When I click on the date , nothing happens to the grid.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that you have forgotten to add the bootstrap.min.js or the bootstrap-datepicker.js **but that you have not added the CSS file to the _Layout partial of your application**.

I had this problem too, when I installed Grid.MVC the javascript got put in the right place, but I forgot to look in my **/Content/ folder** and drag the **gridmvc.datepicker.min.css** file onto my _Layout.  After I did that it rendered fine.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks Kyle , will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the problem you are experiencing.

Since Grid.MVC is based on bootstrap you need to include the following bootstrap scripts in your solution:

1. bootstrap.min.js
2. bootstrap-datepicker.js.

I reproduced your problem by removing the bootstrap-datepicker.js from my solution includes.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks Shadowind , will try and let u know if this works

Comment: Any idea how would it work for datetime not just date bz the filter conditions don't work correctly with datetime.

Since the question is very close so not posting a separate question