# Date filter is not working in GridMvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Grid.mvc in this link:

https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/

When I use Date filter it shows the calendar but by selecting the date nothing is happening. other kind of filters like text and bool are working fine. I already referench the "Grid.Mvc DatePicker"

This is my code:

```
 @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
  {
columns.Add(model => model.dataUser).Titled("User").SetWidth(110);
columns.Add(model => model.Create_Date).Titled("Create Date").SetWidth(110).Filterable(true).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
columns.Add(model => model.Modified_Date).Titled("Modified Date").SetWidth(110).Filterable(true).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
 }).WithPaging(20).Sortable().Filterable().WithMultipleFilters()
```

Comment: Have you added bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap-datepicker.js? check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837665/grid-mvc-date-filter)

Comment: @Hadee yes, I have added.

Comment: I am not sure but may be changing format works. Chang it to : "Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"

Comment: @Hadee have you add any method in your controller for [Httppost]?

Comment: @Hadee I found out the Equal is not working for date , less than and greater than is working!

Comment: have you changed the format?

Comment: @Hadee Yes, same. But now I am getting it refreshed. just the equal is not working. As you suggest problem was bootstrap-datepicker.js.

Comment: So that is only code I have for date column:columns.Add(model => model.Create_Date).Titled("Create Date").SetWidth(110).Filterable(true).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"); (I tested with different date formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to convert DateTime property into Date only.

```
c.Add(x => x.DOB.Date).Titled("Date of Birth").Filterable(true).Sortable(true);
```

For nullable DateTime it would be tricky, the best is to create additional r/o DateOnly property, and use it.