# Grid.MVC date filter "equal" option is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, grid.mvc

I am trying to develop a grid application with using Grid.Mvc. Now I've come to end my application. Bu there's still one unsolved problem about date filter equal option.

There are some old topics about this situation,

[Date filter not working in gridmvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623548/date-filter-not-working-in-gridmvc)

[Date filter is not working in GridMvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658193/date-filter-is-not-working-in-gridmvc)

So I have same situation, greater than and less than filters working good but equal filter is not working. When I click the date with equal option it gives me no results.

I've add these references already.
This is my code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Application.Models.TMP_DATA>


@using GridMvc.Html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Gridmvc.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/gridmvc.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js")"></script>


<div class="code-cut">
    @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
                {

                    columns.Add(s => s.ID).Titled("ID").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.EX_EX1).Titled("TMP1").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.EX_EX2).Titled("TMP2").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.EX_EX3).Titled("TMP3").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.EX_EX4).Titled("TMP4").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.EX_EX5).Titled("TMP5").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.EX_EX6).Titled("TMP6").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.EX_EX7).Titled("TMP7").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.EX_EX8).Titled("TMP8").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.EX_EX9_EX10).Titled("TMP9").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.EX).Titled("TMP10").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.EX_EX11_EX12).Titled("TMP11").SetWidth(200).Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.EX_EX13_EX14_EX15).Titled("TMP12)").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.EX_EX15_EX16_EX17).Titled("TMP13").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.EX_EX17_EX18).Titled("TMP14").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.EX_EX19).Titled("TMP15").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.STBY_1_DIFF).Titled("Stby1DIFF").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.STBY_2_DIFF).Titled("Stby2DIFF").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.STBY_3_DIFF).Titled("Stby3DIFF").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add(s => s.EX_EX20).Titled("TMP16").Filterable(true);
                    columns.Add()
                    .Encoded(false)
                    .Sanitized(false)
                    .SetWidth(30)
                    .RenderValueAs(model => "No: " + model.ID);


                }).WithPaging(50).Sortable(true).WithGridItemsCount("Total TMP")
</div>
```

and my controller is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Application.Models;

namespace Application.Controllers
{
    public class TmpHomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult TmpIndex()
        {
            ExEntities GVDB = new ExEntities();

            var TmpList = (from Tmp in GVDB.TMP_DATA
                           select Tmp).ToList();

            return View(TmpList);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried all of them.
I don't what can I do more about this situation.

From here:https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest
you can find it's resources.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Thanks to all!

Comment: please post your grid code here

Comment: I've posted code for my index and controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try to send just date part from controller action method. This worked for me :)